# Can anyone spot the error with the WITH() clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

SQL is not recognizing the variable I am calling in the main `SELECT` statement. The variable I am calling is the `execs.block_order_quantity`.  I name this variable in the `WITH` statement at the beginning of the query. The code is below, and the error is attached as a picture. I have run the select statement without the `WITH execs as(` piece and it works just fine.

```
WITH execs as(SELECT th.exec_id, SUM(eha.tck_ord_qty) as "BLOCK_ORDER_QUANTITY"  
FROM t1 eha
join t2 th
on eha.exec_id = th.exec_id
where th.trdng_desk_sname IN ('NAME')
and th.trd_dt between to_date('201840101', 'YYYYMMDD')
and to_date ('20140301', 'YYYYMMDD')
and exists
    (SELECT 1
     FROM t2t eth
     WHERE eth.TRD_ID = eha.TRD_ID
     AND eth.trd_stat_cd = 'EX')
group by th.exec_id)
SELECT DISTINCT
th.trd_dt as "TRADE_DATE",
eah.ord_cap_qty as "CAP_AMOUNT",
execs.block_order_quantity as "BLOCK_ORDER_QUANTITY", 
eah.alloc_ovrrd_rsn_cd as "ALLOC_OVRRD_RSN_CD",
  CASE   --create allocation case id 
        WHEN(eh.manl_alloc_ind = 'Y'
            OR NVL (eah.trdr_drct_qty, 0) > 0
            OR NVL (eah.trdr_drct_wgt_ratio, 0) > 0)
        THEN
            'Y'
        ELSE
            'N'
      END 
        AS "ALLOCATION_OVRRD_IND",
      CASE
        WHEN (eh.manl_alloc_ind = 'Y'
             OR NVL (eah.trdr_drct_qty, 0) > 0
             OR NVL (eah.trdr_drct_wgt_ratio, 0) > 0)
        THEN
          TH.EXEC_TMSTMP
        ELSE
          NULL
       END
         AS "ALLOCATION_OVRRD_TIMESTAMP",
eah.alloc_adj_assets_rt_curr_amt as "FUND_ADJ_NET_ASSETS",
eah.as_alloc_exec_hld_qty as "FUND_HOLDINGS_QUANTITY",
th.as_trd_iv_lname as "SECURITY_NAME",
th.as_trd_fmr_ticker_symb_cd as "TICKER",
   CASE  
      WHEN NVL(th.limit_prc_amt, 0) > 0 THEN 'LIMIT' ELSE NULL END
          AS "FUND_ORDER_TYPE"
from t1 eah
join t3 eh
on eah.exec_id = eah.exec_id
join t2 th
on th.trd_id = eah.trd_id
join t4 tk
on tk.tck_id = eah.tck_id
join t5 pm
on eah.pm_person_id_src = pm.person_id_src
where th.trdng_desk_sname IN('NAME')
and th.trd_dt between to_date('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD')
and to_date ('20140301', 'YYYYMMDD')
and rownum < 15
```

[image]

Comment: You have to *reference* the common table expression in the `from` clause of the following `select`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever -- what do you mean by the common table expression in the from clause?  by joining it to something?

Comment: @IzzyFischer - the common table expression (CTE) *is* the `WITH` clause. Your main query refers to `execs.block_order_quantity`, but you haven't included `ececs` in the `from`/`join` clauses. You need to specify how that join should work. Are you sure you actually want that CTE though - it seems to be repeating bits of the main query, so perhaps you really want an analytic sum instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join to the `execs` common table expression (CTE) name in your main query, e.g.:

```
...
from t1 eah
join t3 eh
on eah.exec_id = eah.exec_id
join t2 th
on th.trd_id = eah.trd_id
join execs
on execs.exec_id = eh.exec_id
join t4 tk
...
```

I'm not sure you actually want a CTE here, it looks like you could just do the aggregation in the main query as you're referencing the same tables; but there may be something I'm missing, like duplicates introduced by later joins.

Incidentally, the first `on` clause there looks wrong, as both sides refer to the same column in the same table; so it should probably be:

```
...
from t1 eah
join t3 eh
on eh.exec_id = eah.exec_id
join t2 th
```

Having `distinct` is sometimes a sign that there joins aren't right and there are duplicates you want to suppress which shouldn't really be there, so you may not need that once the join condition is fixed; and that might allow a simple aggregate to work too if it was giving the wrong result before. (Or there could stil be some other reason it's not appropriate.)

Also, the `where rownum < 15` will give an indeterminate set of rows as you aren't ordering the result set before applying that filter.